# How to one to many relation in same table in symfony1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I want to create One to many relation in same table. I have a table category and I tried to create schema for it. I have id of category and parent_id in same table. I want to map them. I tried following code:

```
                 DemoCategory:
                   actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
                   columns:
                     CategoryName  :  { type: string(255) }
                     CategoryImage :  { type: string(255) }
                   relations:
                     DemoCategories:
                        class: DemoCategory
                        refClass: DemoCategory
                        local: ParentCategory
                        foreign: id
                        foreignAlias: DemoCategory
```

When php symfony doctrine:insert-sql it gives error

Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'ParentCategory' doesn't exist in table.

Comment: You tried to create schema for it and got error on insert. So did you succeed or fail trying to create the schema? What does it look like now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error that you see comes from the fact that in your DemoCategories relation doctrine expects **local** to be an **id field** and not a model object.

Now, what you are trying to achieve (with id and parent_id in the same table) is a nested set. And doctrine allows for this kind of model via the NestedSet behaviour. See the doctrine documentation on this here : [doctrine Hierarchical data](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/hierarchical-data.html).

Try this for your model :

```
DemoCategory:
  actAs:
     Timestampable : ~
     NestedSet: ~
  columns:
    CategoryName  :  { type: string(255) }
    CategoryImage :  { type: string(255) }
```

Read the docs, and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks let me try it if there will be any further issue I will post it again.